# Need help to produce correct syntax to free memory for char** when pointer to allocated memory was assign to structure member

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

So basically I cannot figure out what is the problem in my code when I try to free memory for allocated char**. I created char** then allocated memory for it, then I assigned pointer to this char** to the member of my struct. When I am trying to free memory using struct member's pointer I am getting error: 
**malloc:**  error for object 0x796568796568: pointer being freed was not allocated*

Here are some parts of the code:

```
Struct part:
struct TokenizerT_ {
    char **currentToken;
    char **tokens;
}tokenizer;
```

Allocation part (done in separate function):

```
char **words;
    words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (numberOfWords + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
        words[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(ts)+1);


tokenizer.tokens = words;
tokenizer.currentToken = words;
```

Freeing part:

```
int i = 0;
while(*(*tk).tokens){
    free((*tk).tokens[i]);
    i++;
}

free((*tk).tokens);
```

Comment: What's the while condition of the freeing part supposed to accomplish?

Comment: just to free allocated memory that was given to **words

Comment: I was talking about the **condition**, not the loop itself. The way you wrote it, the condition will have the same value after every iteration, since `*(*tk).tokens` never changes. It's equivalent to `while(tk->tokens[0] != NULL)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should realize that `*(*tk).tokens` is equivalent to `(*tk).tokens[0]`. So your loop always checks the same element as stop condition (and that element is not set to `NULL` after being freed so the condition continues to be true).

If you wish to stop the deallocation loop with a `NULL` pointer check, you'd first need to make sure the last element of `words` is assigned `NULL`. Now memory allocated by [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) is not initialized, so you would need to explicitly initialize the last element with:

```
words[numberOfWords] = NULL;
```

Then later when deallocating, you would need to update your loop stop condition to something like:

```
int i = 0;
while((*tk).tokens[i]){
    free((*tk).tokens[i]);
    i++;
}
free((*tk).tokens);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "words[i] = 0;" to the assigning part, to make your while loop stop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
    words[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(ts)+1);
words[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Well, it is not a problem of while loop or for loop... it is really a problem of the fact that I am getting error malloc: error for object 0x796568796568: pointer being freed was not allocated*

Comment: You have assigned value (allocated memory) to words[0 ~ (numberOfWords - 1)] in for loop, but do nothing to words[numberOfWords]. The value of words[numberOfWords] might not be 0 and it probably cause your while loop keep freeing non-stop. So, set the words[numberOfWords] to 0 (as my answer) to let the while loop, "while(*(*tk).tokens)", stop when checking words[numberOfWords].

Comment: My bad, you need to change this "while(*(*tk).tokens)" to "while((*tk).tokens[i])" too. You are always checking the same memory.